# What image-editor or library produces an easy-to-use 2D vector format describing areas / masks?

Tags: graphics, image, vector-graphics, image-editor

Step

1. Administrative / data entry worker opens **?**, loads raster image, and using a 'lasso-like' tool (a la Photoshop 'magnetic' if possible) specifies areas of interest / masks.
2. **?**
3. Profit! (i.e., application opens raster image, vector file describing masks, does interesting stuff to areas of interest based on runtime context)

My question is "what do we use for steps 1 and 2 **?** "

- Primary goal is to reduce the time required to complete Steps 1 and 2 (the 'mechanical Turk' part of the process).
- Strictly secondary goal is the ease of parsing / using the vector format describing the areas of interest / masks in step 3.

> **Water cooler conversation:**
>
> 'Sheesh, there's got to be some Flash
> component that does this!"
>
> "What about GIMP?"
>
> "If we have to put C or
> C++ programmers on it, it's not going to be a good investment...."
>
> "But what if it only takes a day or two?" "Nothing takes just a day or
> two," ....

For prototyping, the obvious route is **Photoshop -> Illustrator -> SVG**.

But if there's a framework / library / editor that could make the 'lasso' coding and vector-file generation easy, it might tip the scales in favor of writing a custom editor.

Is there such a framework / library / editor?

Comment: Question: why does the output have to be a vector file? Any operation taken on a raster image is most likely to generate a raster output. Generating a vector is probably an extra step, and one that loses data rather than gaining it.

Comment: +1 for step 1/2/3 :)  
And if my info would help, I solved the same problem by using OBJ (Alias|Wavefront). But I implemented parsing myself (it was 1998, I think...)